# How to link a listbox to a folder that automatically updates upon changes in the folder

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to link my `listbox` to a folder where if a user upload a excel file into the folder the listbox will automatically update the `listbox`. Any ideas of how I could even start this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst this can be done using VBA, it is normal to allow the user to browse a folder (often filtered to show only files of a certain type). If you do want to do it this way, you need to create a small VBA function that loops the folder in question and creates a string of file names:

```
Public Function fListFiles(strFolder As String) As String
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim strFile As String
    strFile = Dir(strFolder, vbNormal)
    Do
        If InStr(strFile, ".xl") > 0 Then
            fListFiles = fListFiles & strFile & ";"
        End If
        strFile = Dir
    Loop Until strFile = ""
    If Right(fListFiles, 1) = ";" Then fListFiles = Left(fListFiles, Len(fListFiles) - 1)
fExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Function
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "fListFiles", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume fExit
End Function
```

Then, in your form, set the list box's `RowSource` to be "Value List", put the following code in the Form's `Timer` event:

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    Me!lstFile.RowSource = fListFiles("J:\downloads\")
End Sub
```

Finally, change the Form's Timer Interval from 0 (60,000 is 1 minute).

Regards,

Comment: I have tried it. It does not work, do you have any idea why. I changed the ".xl" to ".xlsx" as my file extension is that. I have also change the fListFiles directory to the one I want. But the list still does not auto populate. I also didn't receive any error message box when I run the code.

Comment: Several things to check. Firstly, do you have a backslash at the end of the directory path? Next, in the immediate window (accessed through Ctl-G), type `?fListFiles("J:\downloads\")` to see if it returns a list of files as expected. Next, put a `Debug.Print fListFiles` in the procedure just before `E_Handle:` and see if it outputs the same text to the immediate window.

Comment: I have done the following steps. The error that it shows is Error: 5, invalid procedure call or argument fListFiles. I also change the fListFiles to the desired folder that I want to check the files is something like this ("C:\Users\MOMUAB\Desktop\Polling_Folders")

Comment: I have done it. I have returned the values I wanted but the list box still does not auto update. Any ideas?

Comment: You need a backslash at the end of the folder path.

Comment: I have done that and at the immediate window it does return me the values that I desire. But the list box still does not populate. Any ideas?

Comment: What value have you set for the Form's Timer Interval? Also, put a `Debug.Print fListFiles("C:\Users\MOMUAB\Desktop\Polling_Folders\")` in the Form's Timer code to see if that prints to the immediate window

Comment: I have input 60,000 for the time interval and when I put the debug code into the form timer event and insert a "?" into the window it does not return me anything.

Comment: I have waited a minute and it works. Thanks alot applecore going to ace my internship with this! But is there a way to make it immediate upon opening the form?

Comment: Good - please mark this as the answer then. You could also put `Me!lstFile.RowSource = fListFiles("J:\downloads\")` in the form's `OnLoad` event so that it populates the list when the form is opened.

Comment: Thanks it works! How do I mark this as answer? Sorry I'm a very new to this, join like last 12 hours.